# $C^2([0,1])$ is not complete with respect to $C_1$ norm

Tags: analysis

I want to prove that $C^2([0,1])$ is not complete with respect to $C_1$ norm, which is defined as $$||f||_{C_1}=||f||_\infty+||f^\prime||_\infty.$$

Comment: This makes no sense notationally.

Comment: Do you think it is impossible? I find this problem in my homework.

Comment: I may have been a little too quick with my comment. What do you mean by $C^2([0,1])$? (The notation is often used for the space of square integrable continuous functions on $[0,1]$).

Comment: I have retracted my close vote on the presumption that you are referring to the space of square integrable continuous functions.

Comment: I mean twice continuously differentiable function space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@copper.hat** already constructed a nice counter-example, but I would also like to contribute by giving a counter-example which is also easy to compute. Let $f_{\epsilon}$ for $\epsilon > 0$ by

$$f_{\epsilon}(x) = x \sqrt{x^2 + \epsilon}.$$

Then $f_{\epsilon}$ is smooth and its pointwise limit $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} f_{\epsilon}(x) = x |x| =: f(x)$ is in $C^1([0, 1])$ but not in $C^2([0, 1])$. Now notice that for any $x \in [0, 1]$,

$$ | f_{\epsilon}(x) - f(x)| = |x| \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{x^2 + \epsilon} + |x|} \leq \sqrt{\epsilon}$$

and similarly

$$ | f'_{\epsilon}(x) - f'(x)| = \left| 2\sqrt{x^2 + \epsilon} - 2|x| - \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{x^2 + \epsilon}} \right| \leq 3\sqrt{\epsilon}.$$

This shows that $\| f_{\epsilon} - f \|_{C^1} \leq 4\sqrt{\epsilon} \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$. Therefore we have a sequence of functions in $C^2([0, 1])$ which is Cauchy but cannot converge to an element of $C^2([0, 1])$. This implies that $C^2([0, 1])$ is not complete with respect to $C^1$-norm.

---

A more abstract and indirect way is as follows: Let $I = [0, 1]$. Then

- $C^1(I)$ is complete with respect to $C^1$-norm, and
- $C^2(I)$ is a proper subspace of $C^1(I)$.

So it suffices to show that $C^2(I)$ is not closed in $C^1(I)$.

One way to prove this is to establish a slightly stronger statement that $C^2(I)$ is dense in $C^1(I)$. This automatically guarantees that $C^2(I)$ is not closed, for otherwise $C^2(I)$ is equal to the closure of a dense subset, which is all of $C^1(I)$, a contradiction!

So how would we prove that $C^2(I)$ is dense in $C^1(I)$ with respect to $C^1$-norm? This can be done in many ways, but one standard machinery is to explicitly approximate any $f \in C^1(I)$ by mollifying it. For instance, consider $\varphi \in C^{\infty}(\Bbb{R})$ such that

$$ \varphi \geq 0 \quad \text{and} \quad \int_{\Bbb{R}} \varphi(x) \, dx = 1. $$

Then define $(f_n)$ for each $f \in C^1(I)$ by

$$ f_n(x) = \int_I f(t) \varphi_n(x - t) \, dt. $$

One can check that $f_n$ is smooth and $f_n \to f$ in $C^1$. (This is not hard, but may be burdensome to write down all the details.)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are talking about the space of twice continuously   differentiable functions.

For convenience, I will deal with the domain $[-1,1]$ instead of $[0,1]$.

Here are some hints:

Let $h_n(x) = {2 \over \pi} \arctan (nx)$, $g_n(x) = \int_0^x h_n(x) dx$ and
$f_n(x) = \int_0^x g_n(x)dx$.

It is not hard to show that all of these functions are smooth, and
$f_n' = g_n, g_n' = h_n$.

Show that $f_n$ is Cauchy with respect to the norm in the question.

Show that the pointwise limit of $h_n$ is $\lim_n h_n(x) = \operatorname{sgn} x$.

Conclude that $f_n$ has no limit in terms of the given norm (it is straightforward using contradiction).

Comment: (+1) I am pretty sure you intended to use $h_n(x) = \frac{2}{\pi}\arctan (nx)$.

Comment: @SangchulLee: Thank you for catching that!

Comment: Something happened?